# Parallel message handling using azure-sb

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azureservicebus

What's the behaviour of `serviceBusService.receiveQueueMessage()` in regards to parallel processing? Can't find anything in the unfortunately brief Microsoft docs.

Singleton listener **OR** async handler with max number of active messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`serviceBusService.receiveQueueMessage` will take one message and process it. You can have logic to call this method parallel if you want but problem could be that if you have long processing messages and you are pulling faster than processing you can get into trouble or you need to manage how many to pull your self.

Looks like there is new librarry `[@azure/service-bus][1]` where you can [register message handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/receiver?view=azure-node-latest#registermessagehandler-onmessage--onerror--messagehandleroptions-) to process multiple messages

```
const myMessageHandler = async (message) => {
  // your code here
};
const myErrorHandler = (error) => {
  console.log(error);
};
receiver.registerMessageHandler(myMessageHandler, myErrorHandler, {maxConcurrentCalls: 10});
```